# My site works on desktop but not on mobile. Lots of JavaScript involved. Any ideas how to diagnose this?

Tags: javascript

https://plutownium.github.io/ASCII-Pathfinding-Visualizer/?

This is my ASCII Pathfinding Visualizer. I built it and it works fine on desktop, but on mobile...

- the "Visualize Dijkstra's" button does not work: You can place a Start Node and a Target Node, click the button, and have the visualizer fail to start.
- the "Generate Recursive division maze" button does not work: You can generate a random maze, you can generate a binary tree maze, but the Recursive Division maze button does nothing.

To make things more confusing: As far as I can tell, it works on all 3 of Chrome, Brave and Firefox on my desktop. But when my phone loads it up, neither the Safari browser nor the Chrome browser works.

I am stuck for how to debug it, because I don't have access to the Developer Tools (and hence not the console.log output either) on Mobile.

Further I have no foundation of knowledge for *why* something would work fine on desktop but not on mobile. So while I am suspicious it is some kind of cross-compatibility issue (it must be right?),  I cannot begin to understand what part of the code would be causing the issue.

I would show some code but I'm really not sure what part of the code to show. It is approximately a thousand lines of JavaScript between three files. Of course, two of the Maze Generation buttons work, so that narrows it down a lot, but... I am still stuck. Like, I can find plenty of StackOverflow links about "JavaScript doesn't work on mobile", but I'm not sure how those help me since I can't even access details about the cause of my problem -- I have no idea which lines of code are broken and I can't access that info (no dev tools on mobile).

What do I do?

edit: I still don't understand how code can work on desktop but not on mobile.

Comment: What happens if you emulate a mobile browser in your Chrome DevTools?

Comment: [I don't have access to the Developer Tools (and hence not the console.log output either) on Mobile](https://www.google.com/search?q=developer+tools+android+chrome&oq=developer+tools+android+chrome&aqs=chrome.0.0l8.4093j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: It works when I emulate a mobile browser in my Chrome devtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking the "visualize Dijkstra's" button on an iPhone, the console error reads:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Path
    dijkstras — dijkstras.js:147
    (anonymous function) — script.js:593
```

The code fragment in dijkstras.js:

```
if (iteration == 0) { // while iteration==0, STARTING_NODE===CurrentNode, so it's unique: There is no path to get there.
            const firstEntry = [startValueX, startValueY]
            const initPath = new Path(0, [], firstEntry, false) // Can't find variable: Path

            potentialPaths.push(initPath)
        } else { // block summary: generate a new Path to add to potentialPaths
```

**UPDATE**

The same ReferenceError occurs on desktop Safari.

**UPDATE 2**

Upon load, Safari reports a syntax error in file `classes.js`, line 18:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='. Expected an opening '(' before a method's parameter list.
    (anonymous function) — classes.js:18
```

File classes.js:

```js
class Cell {
    offset = 2; // *** SyntaxError ***
```

Comment: How do you access the console error on an iPhone? I don't understand how you saw that error message using an iPhone. Thanks for your investigation...

Comment: @RolyPoly You connect the iOS device to a desktop Mac that's running Safari. Details here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html